# Get the output of lsof command Python 3.5

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I am trying to do a script that listen to a directory waiting to new files, then send to a Nextcloud. The files may be big ones,so I want to check if they are complete before sending. I thought about using lsof +D path/to/directory and check if the files are in the output of the command and send them when the file is not. The code would be something like:

```
command=list()
command.append("lsof")
command.append("+D")
command.append("/path/to/dir")
lsof = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
```

But I get subprocess.CalledProcessError returned non-zero exit status 1

Can someone help to ecexute the command and get the output into the variable?

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['lsof', '+D', '/home/CLI2Cache/sync']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace? Problems like these are pretty hard to solve from an answer's perspective because we can't replicate your environment. You're making a system call: so the environment will be important.

Comment: Try removing the space between stderr, the equal sign and subprocess.STDOUT to look like `lsof = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: I've edited the post with the full traceback. Tried removing the spaces between stderr but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of workarounds for this. You can use `shell=True` in the `check_output` -

```
lsof = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Please note that `shell=True` is not safe as it also gives access to a lot of shell commands which might lead to some vulnerabilities if the command is user-specified or not sanitized properly. Please go through [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) to understand the risks.

A better way would be to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) -

```
lsof = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    output, errs = lsof.communicate(timeout=20)
except TimeoutExpired:
    lsof.kill()
    output, errs = proc.communicate()
```

`communicate` is also useful, if you want to send the input to the spawned process and get corresponding output at each step.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Tried both ways, none worked.
With subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT) i get just the output of "lsof" withour parameters into the variable.
With subprocess.Popen(command, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT) i get the right output. but it does not set the variable, only prints the data i want to set into a variable (if then i use lsof.communicate() i get (None, None) ). Not sure if the problem is the interpreter or the code

Comment: I've added "stdout = subprocess.PIPE" as parameter in the popen and goes perfect. Thanks a lot Jay!